# Cerrar AlertDialog desde otra Actividad

Tags: android-studio

¡Hola Todos! Tengo un AlertDialog muy simple, sólo con un mensaje de "Procesando...". No hay botones, ni título ni nada. Lo muestro al pasar de una Actividad a otra porque la segunda hace algunas consultas a la BD y tarda en aparecer. De hecho, eso funciona de maravilla. El problema es que si me regreso a la primera actividad, el AlertDialog sigue activo.
En concreto, mi pregunta es: ¿Hay manera de cerrar el AlertDialog de la primera Actividad DESDE la segunda Actividad? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: porque no lo inicias en la segunda actividad antes de cargar la vista y la ejecución de las peticiones?, de esa manera con el onBack lo cierras o al finalizar de mostrar las consultas que estas generando., en todo caso, seria bueno que coloques el código asociado a la secuencia de eventos para poder ayudarte mejor, la pregunta esta muy `pobre y genérica.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Carlos, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento debes modificar tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado (**tu código**)  e investigado, saludos!

Comment: Gracias Carlos y Jorge por sus comentarios. Creo que mi pregunta es bastante clara y concreta: Independientemente de mi caso o situación, ¿se puede cerrar un AlertDialog desde otra Actividad diferente a la que lo lanzó?. Creo que el código sobra. De igual manera, voy a repensar la pregunta y la modifico. Muchas gracias.